# flip clock callbacks stop - no me funciona

Tags: contador

estimados estoy utilizando flipclock para un contador regresivo, lo que intento es que al llegar al tiempo indicado, el contador haga un callback stop y ocultar el div del contador y mostrar otro div con un mensaje, cuando hice el ejemplo solo con minutos funciona pero necesito con fecha, y no me esta funcionado. podrían darme la mano gracias, dejo lo códigos que utilizo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    iniciarTemporizador();
});

function iniciarTemporizador() {

    var fechaFinal = new Date(2018, 2, 15, 12, 59, 59);
    var fechaHoy = new Date();

    var diferenciaMilisegundos = fechaFinal.getTime() - fechaHoy.getTime();
    var diferenciaSegundos = (diferenciaMilisegundos / 1000);

    var clock = $(".clock").FlipClock({
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        autoStart: false,
        callbacks: {
            stop: function() {
                
                $('.clock').fadeOut();
                $('.nuevo-mensaje').fadeIn();

            }
        }
    });

    clock.setTime(diferenciaSegundos);
    clock.setCountdown(true);
    clock.start();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css">

<div class="clock"></div>
<div class="nuevo-mensaje" style="display:none;">Contenido del nuevo mensaje!!!</div>
```

Comment: lo que pasa es que flipclock funciona maximo con dias solamente para mostrar, pero cuado cambias la fecha , por ejemplo el año y le pones 2019, el contador de segundo cambia a 3 digitos (como 500 segundos aprox), y si lo cambias a 2050 cambia a 5 digitos como a (como 30.000 segundos) , y a partir de ahí empieza la cuenta regresiva . Con eso hace que llegue a la fecha que corresponde.

Comment: te dejo el link de donde dice cual es lo maximo que muestra [flipclock](http://flipclockjs.com/faces/daily-counter), ademas para poder hacer que llegue a la fehca que quieres vas a tener que transformarla a horas.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, con la fecha, que necesito llegar no hay problema, solo quiero que cuando llega la fecha indicada, el .clock se esconda y se muestre el .nuevo-mensaje, si te comprendo no se puede por un tema de dígitos, lo cual no entiendo bien, y no necesito transformar nada así como esta me va bien solo quiero, ocultar y mostrar el div correspondiente cuando llegue el tiempo o fecha indicada, que le pueda indicar.

Comment: Pues no encuentro solución, alguien alguna idea, que podría probar, gracias.